# Trying to get property 'usu_id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de importar datos desde `excel` a mi base de datos en `laravel` y me encontre con ese problema que no me habia pasado antes, antes funcionaba bien. Estoy obteniendo por medio de una consulta un id e importandolo a mi base de datos así :

```
$id=tbl_usuario::select('usu_id')->join('tbl_laboratorio','tbl_laboratorio.lab_usu_id','=','tbl_usuario.usu_id')
    ->where('tbl_laboratorio.lab_cliente','=',$row['cliente'])->first();
    $onlyId=$id->usu_id;

return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_codigo'   => $row['codigo_ellipse'],
        'ins_observacionInicial'   => $row['observaciones_iniciales'],
        'ins_proximaCalibracion'=>$proximaCal,
        'ins_fechaUltimaCalibracion'=>$ultimaCal,
        'ins_claseOexactitud'    => $row['clase_de_exactitud'],
        'ins_nSerie' => $row['numero_de_serie'],
        'ins_divOescala'=>$row['division_de_escala'],
        'ins_consecutivoInterno' => $row['consecutivo_interno'],
        'ins_observaciones' =>$row['observaciones'],
        'ins_observacionFinal' => $row['observaciones_finales'],
        'ins_magnitud' => $row['magnitud'],
        'ins_modelo' => $row['modelo'],
        'ins_codActividad' => $row['codigo_de_actividad'],
        'ins_usu_id' =>  $onlyId,
        'ins_tipo_id' => $tipo->tipo_id,
        'ins_mar_id' => $marca->mar_id,
    ]);
```

Revisando el error en unos foros me encontre con una "solucion" la cual era la siguiente ponerlo así:

```
$onlyId=$id['usu_id'];
```

Pero esto me trajo el siguiente error:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

Revise con `dd($id)` y me trae lo siguiente:

```
 App\tbl_usuario {#702 ▼
  #primaryKey: "usu_id"
  +timestamps: false
  +table: "tbl_usuario"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:1 [▶]
  #original: array:1 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}
```

No se si me deberia traer eso el id, a lo mejor lo estoy haciendo mal pero no encuentro cual podria ser el error al hacer `dd($onlyId)` si me trae un valor numerico el cual es el id que requiero.

Comment: Has verificado que el query efectivamente arroja resultados? Debes ser más cuidadoso, y hacer algo `if(!$id) return "No hay registros para ese cliente"` para que controles eso. Si aún no solucionas esto, te recomendaría poner lo que el `dd($id)` arroja.

Comment: @L.Flor `dd($id)` me trae un valor numerico, y me trae el valor que debe, trae un numero por ejemplo 17, lo cual es el id del usuario que busco

Comment: Normalmente el método `first()`de Eloquent debe retornar la instancia de un modelo. No debería retornar un simple número. `$onlyId=$id->usu_id;` sí debería retornar un número ya que estás accediendo.

Comment: @L.Flor Si correcto disculpa me confundi yo, ya edite la pregunta con lo que me trae `dd($id)`

Comment: Efectivamente es la instancia de un modelo. Debes tener en cuenta que `first()` debe ser accedido así `$id->usu_id`. Y no así `$id['usu_id'];`

Comment: @L.Flor Si estoy haciendolo como dices, lo hago en el `$onlyId=$id->usu_id;` Pero al hacer el import me dice `Trying to get property 'usu_id' of non-object`

Comment: Eso es normal y suele pasar debido a que no hay registros que cumplan la condición de tu `where()` y por ende, returna `null`. Realiza la consulta en tu gestor de base de datos y verifica que la consulta retorne resultados.

Comment: @L.Flor Ya vi el error, fue un fallo con una macro que tengo en excel para pasar los datos allí y me estaba enviando unas filas vacias. Gracias por la ayuda